# Sending a POST request with complicated, multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, post, parameters, request

I'm building a RESTful system and I wonder: what is the best way to send a POST request using JavaScript when as a parameters(?) or a request body(?) I need to send a big text in XML, several simplier strings and text files? How should I do that? Should I use just a request body or query parameters in URL? And what content-type should I use then?

I'd like to do something like:

```
var url = "/server";  
xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
xmlHttp.send(xmlString);
```

But that is enough just for one needed thing - a xml text.

Comment: To be RESTful you don't want to send parameters via url if it will cause data to be updated, only if it will not change state of underlying data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer. It seems to me that the best way to do it is to use Content-Type multipart/mixed and separate data with a boundary. Then I can give every part its own type, set its name and then read it easily in server (using Jersey, MultiPart class and reading BodyParts from it).